# Blurry Textures when calculating normals

Tags: unity-game-engine, normals

I'm calculating the normals of a mesh that I've generated using the marching cubes algorithm but when I run it the object looks blurry like in the picture.
[image: Image of a mesh generated using the code]

Variables:
CurrentTri is a Vector3int with the indexes of each vertex
CurrentNorm is a Vector3 with the current normal
Verts is a Vector3 array of the positions of the vertices
VertNorm is a Vector3 array of the normals of the vertices

The c# code where I calculate the normals:

```
// Repeated for each triangle
CurrentNorm = Vector3.Cross(Verts[CurrentTri.y] - Verts[CurrentTri.x], Verts[CurrentTri.z] - Verts[CurrentTri.x]);

VertNorm[CurrentTri.x] += CurrentNorm;
VertNorm[CurrentTri.y] += CurrentNorm;
VertNorm[CurrentTri.z] += CurrentNorm;
```

Normalising the normals:

```
for(int i = 0; i < VertNorm.Length; i++)
{
    VertNorm[i] = VertNorm[i].normalized;
}
mesh.normals = VertNorm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to be like that (I think). I was a complete idiot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).